# How do I take a screenshot in a form of a video on my iPod touch 5G?

Tags: ios, youtube, screenshot

I have a YouTube channel which I post game reviews and best apps videos. I am currently using my old ipod to record but since I have quite a lot of subscribers I want the video quality to be better. Is there any app I can download to take a screen video on a non jailbroken iPod touch 5G.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Please find a more appropriate place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can share screen of your iPod to your desktop computer using AirPlay and record screencast from this computer. It will look like you recorded screen of your iPod. For this you will need anything like this: http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/record-iphone-screen/

Or you can try solution from Apple Support Community: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4893020?start=0&tstart=0
They suggest following:

> Get RecordMyScreen from emu4ios.weebly.com on your iPhone. Sroll down
>   untill you find RecordMyScreen then press install. When it asks if you
>   want to install the app press indtall. It may take more than one try,
>   so if it doesn't work the first time tap retry. I have it and it works
>   great.